# Changing parent and background color of a label dynamically during drag on various locations of my form

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

My form has two panels, each of them having two different background images and few labels on the side. I am trying to use drag and drop functionality where my labels can be moved and be placed on anywhere on the form or inside any of the two panels during run time, the problem that I am facing is I am unable to set a transparent background label or parent because the user may drag and place the label on any of the two panels according to their choice, so the label parent also changes dynamically during drag. I need a transparent background label after it is dropped anywhere on any of the panel. Below is my code for dragging. Kindly help me :-

```
    private void NameLabel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
    }

    private void NameLabel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            NameLabel.Left = e.X + NameLabel.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
            NameLabel.Top = e.Y + NameLabel.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to roll-your- Drag and drop, which is fair enough. However, you might want to look at the Drag and Drop supplied methods and plumbing for your applications i.e winforms or Wpf, it has everything you need and all the events to achieve what you desire

Comment: Any link from where I can achieve this ? I am unable to find a proper one.

Comment: winforms or wpf

Comment: I am using winfroms

Comment: Any help? I am in serious trouble.